# How to let the icon scale with a QtPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, button, icons

How can i let the icon of a QtPushButton scale with the button when it shrinks/grows?

I have already tried just setting the new icon size when a resize event has occured. But that just triggered a resize event itself and crashed the program.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Qt will only downscale the icons and will never upscale. So to implement the functionality you request you have to prepare a "big" version of the icon (or several versions with different scales and assign them all to the same QIcon object).

Read here for more information: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html